# Select head of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Now, I'm still learning haskell (to configure my xmonad wm), so bear with me.

I've written this function:

```
doesNameBeginWith :: String -> Query Bool
doesNameBeginWith str = fmap ( str `isPrefixOf`) (stringProperty "WM_NAME")
```

Which will check the start of the WM_NAME X property against my str. I can compose it like this:

```
isMusic = doesNameBeginWith "MPD:" <||> doesNameBeginWith "ncmpcpp"
```

It works. Now I want to write a functions with this signature:

```
[String] -> Query Bool
```

so that I can call it like this:

```
isMusic = doesNameBeginWith ["MPD:", "ncmpcpp"]
```

The idea was to use foldr1 to parse the string list, but I can't figure out the sintax to get the head of the list... something like this:

```
doesNameBeginWith :: [String] -> Query Bool
doesNameBeginWith str = foldr1 (<||>) . fmap ( (head str) `isPrefixOf`) (stringProperty "WM_NAME")
```

EDIT 1: as [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) suggested, I can combine two functions to get what I want:

```
doesNameBeginWithL :: [String] -> Query Bool
doesNameBeginWithL = foldr1 (<||>) . map doesNameBeginWith
```

But I'm still hoping for a more direct way and to understand how list heads could be used in this situation!

EDIT 2: Thank you all again for your answers, all of them have been quite informative! :)

Comment: You can use pattern matching e.g. `f "" = ... ; f (x:xs) = ... ` so that you can access the head `x`. The `foldr1` approach looks much better, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a list, you don't need to parse it – you can simply *deconstruct* it.

```
isThisStuff :: [String] -> Query Bool
isThisStuff [c,d] = doesNameBeginWith c <||> doesNameBeginWith d
```

Then

```
isMusic = isThisStuff ["MPD:", "ncmpcpp"]
```

Note that this fails if the supplied list doesn't have exactly two elements.

Arguably, a fold-based solution *is* better. As you've noted, this can be written

```
foldr1 (<||>) . map doesNameBeginWith
```

Now, all you need to do to get rid of `doesNameBeginWith` in there is to *inline* it. Note that

```
doesNameBeginWith = \str -> fmap ( str `isPrefixOf`) (stringProperty "WM_NAME")
```

So you can use

```
foldr1 (<||>) . map (\str -> fmap ( str `isPrefixOf`) (stringProperty "WM_NAME"))
```

If you don't like the lambda, you can formulate this as a list comprehension:

```
doesNameBeginWithAny strs = foldr1 (<||>)
     [fmap ( str `isPrefixOf`) (stringProperty "WM_NAME") | str <- strs]
```

Alternatively, you can make `doesNameBeginWith` point-free

```
doesNameBeginWith = \str -> fmap (isPrefixOf str) (stringProperty "WM_NAME")            
                  = \str -> flip fmap (stringProperty "WM_NAME") (isPrefixOf str)
                  = \str -> flip fmap (stringProperty "WM_NAME") . isPrefixOf $ str
                  = flip fmap (stringProperty "WM_NAME") . isPrefixOf
                  = (stringProperty "WM_NAME" `fmap`) . isPrefixOf
```

so

```
doesNameBeginWithAny = foldr1 (<||>)
                     . map ((stringProperty "WM_NAME" `fmap`) . isPrefixOf)
```

## However

all of this is overly complicated. It gets much simpler when you split up the problem:

1. Retrieve `stringProperty "WM_NAME"` in the `Query` monad.
2. Match any of the supplied strings with it.

   ```
   doesNameBeginWithAny :: String -> Query Bool
   doesNameBeginWithAny prefs = do
      wmName <- stringProperty "WM_NAME"
      return $ any (`isPrefixOf`wmName) prefs
   ```

This can also written with `fmap`, as Freerich Raabe showed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is *almost* what I need! :) I was looking for a more direct way (also, I DO want to learn how to use list heads), but combining two functions I can indeed obtain the desired result; I'll update my question and wait some more time for other answers.

Comment: I *do* like the lambda, I will go for that to inline the function :) Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the function you're mapping over the the string property a bit; the [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) function comes in handy. Instead of

```
doesNameBeginWith str = fmap ( str `isPrefixOf`) (stringProperty "WM_NAME")
```

try

```
doesNameBeginWith xs  = fmap (\x -> any (`isPrefixOf` x) xs) (stringProperty "WM_NAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

As you realised, `head` is how you can get the first element of the list, but the solution I'd teach to newbies is to use *pattern-matching* and recursion to access list elements. Using your first definition of `doesNameBeginWith`:

```
doesNameBeginAny :: [String] -> Query Bool
doesNameBeginAny (x:xs) = doesNameBeginWith x <||> doesNameBeginAny xs
doesNameBeginAny [] = return False
```

After the type declaration, there are two cases. One case takes a list with at least one item (`x`), and calls your first function on that one item, combining the result with a recursive call on the rest of the list (`xs`, which may be empty). The pattern matching is responsible for taking apart the list to get at the first item each time, so you don't need to call `head`. The second case handles the empty list.

As you've already found, the function `foldr1` (as well as the other folds) abstracts away this structure of the function. You can use a map to transform the list into a list of `Query Bool`, and then a fold to reduce the list to a single item by or'ing the elements together.

```
doesNameBeginAny xs = foldr (<||>) False queries
    where queries = map doesNameBeginWith xs
```

I've used `where` to define an intermediate to make the code easier to follow. I've also used `foldr` rather than `foldr1` so the function also works on empty lists. Again, you don't need to call `head` because `map` and `fold` are responsible for taking apart the list.

If you're looking for an answer that pulls apart the list explicitly, more like a for-each loop in Python or Java or some other imperative language, that's just not how you write Haskell.